# picking a DataRow Based on maximum of certain field and criteria using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

here is my code (which doesn't work, obviously) .But, Could not figure out how to achieve this...

```
DataRow dRow =  dsMain.tblStudentMaster.Select("stM_ClassNo=VI")).Max<DataRow>(row => row["StudentRollNo"]);
```

In a particular ClassRoom, I want to pick up student having Maximum Roll No. 
Well, I want that DataRow and not the RollNo (which is obviously available once I get that row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to order the rows accordingly:

```
DataRow dRow =  dsMain.tblStudentMaster.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<int>("StudentRollNo"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

(assuming that the type of the column `StudentRollNo` is `int`)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `MaxBy` extension method from [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs?r=2da75c30d5bda7959e5113b702b4bb204a0e4a2c)

`dsMain.tblStudentMaster.MaxBy(item => item.FieldYouWantMaxFrom);`